# Sort Wordpress Posts Meta value by Week not Day

Tags: wp-query, query, sort

Right now I have a metakey called 'epicredvote', it sorts my posts by this epicredvote number. It is doing it on a daily basis at the moment, so if I have 2 posts the post with the highest epicredvote # will be at the top. I am wanting to sort it by the WEEK not the DAY. I am wanting all my posts for that week to then be ordered by the epicredvote. With the highest # being at the top.

```
$querystr = ”
SELECT $wpdb->posts.*, YEAR(post_date) AS year,
MONTH(post_date) AS month,
DAYOFMONTH(post_date) AS dayofmonth
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = ‘epicredvote’
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = ‘publish’
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = ‘post’
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY LEFT($wpdb->posts.post_date, 10) DESC, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
“;
```

Please any help with this would be amazing. Thanks to all you dev rockstars!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Rarst about the WEEK function, but be sure to also use YEAR as well to order the posts. So your order by would look something like this:

```
ORDER BY YEAR($wpdb->posts.post_date) DESC, WEEK($wpdb->posts.post_date) DESC, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
```

Of course, this is still pulling all posts, so you might also want to just limit the query to only pull the current year by adding this to your WHERE clause.

```
AND YEAR($wpdb->posts.post_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an MySQL question than WordPress one.

You are already using date functions there, from a quick check there is (unsurprisingly) one for [`WEEK(date[,mode])`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week), you could use in similar fashion for order.